# Data binding for data template does not work .net 4.0 but works 4.5

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have meet a problem that the data binding not work correctly in .NET framework 4.0, below is the snapshot, the top combobox is work correctly, but below 3 combobox with red rectangle not work as expected (all the comboboxs should display "B" by default, just like the top one does)

[image]

Below is the snapshot while open the drop down list
[image]

**But the same applicaiton work correctly on the machine that installed .NET framework 4.5**, below is the snapshot

[image]

Below is the related source code (**the target framework for the project is .NET Framework 4**)

File EnumItem.cs (the purpose of this class is to support localization)

```
using System;

namespace Test.Enums
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is provide a enum list item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public class EnumItem<T> where T : struct
    {
        public EnumItem(T enumValue)
        {
            if(!typeof(T).IsEnum)
                throw new NotSupportedException("The supported generic type is only enum.");

            EnumValue = enumValue;
        }

        public T EnumValue { get; set; }

        public string DisplayString
        { // To make code cleaner, did not get string from resource file 
            get { return EnumValue.ToString(); }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return DisplayString;
        }
    }
}
```

File EnumUtil.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test.Enums
{
    public static class EnumUtil<T> where T : struct
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Traverse all the enum values and encapsulate to a EnumItem list.
        /// </summary>
        public static List<EnumItem<T>> GetEnumItems()
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            if (!type.IsEnum)
                throw new NotSupportedException("The supported generic type is only enum.");

            var enumItems = new List<EnumItem<T>>();
            foreach (var val in Enum.GetValues(type))
            {
                var item = new EnumItem<T>((T)val);
                enumItems.Add(item);
            }

            return enumItems;
        }
    }
}
```

File VMBase.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Test.Base
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The base class for all the view model classes
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

File MainVM.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Test.Base;
using Test.Enums;
using TestDemo;

namespace ItemTemplate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Hardware Series
    /// </summary>
    public enum HwSeries
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Series A
        /// </summary>
        A,

        B
    }

    internal class MainVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        private HwSeries series_ = HwSeries.B;
        public HwSeries Series
        {
            get { return series_; }
            set
            {
                if (series_ != value)
                {
                    series_ = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Series");
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Hardware Series
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<EnumItem<HwSeries>> HwSeriesCollection { get; private set; }

        private ObservableCollection<SubVM> cascadingList_ = new ObservableCollection<SubVM>();

        public MainVM ()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            HwSeriesCollection = new ObservableCollection<EnumItem<HwSeries>>(
                EnumUtil<HwSeries>.GetEnumItems());

            for (var pairNumber = 1; pairNumber < 4; pairNumber++)
            {
                var cascading = new SubVM();
                cascadingList_.Add(cascading);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SubVM> CascadingList
        {
            get { return cascadingList_; }
        }

    }
}
```

File SubVM.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using ItemTemplate;
using Test.Base;
using Test.Enums;

namespace TestDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cascading Plug-in View Model
    /// </summary>
    public class SubVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Hardware Series
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<EnumItem<HwSeries>> HwSeriesCollection { get; private set; }


        public void InitializeItemSources()
        {
            HwSeriesCollection = new ObservableCollection<EnumItem<HwSeries>>
                (EnumUtil<HwSeries>.GetEnumItems());
        }

        public SubVM()
        {
            InitializeItemSources();
        }

        private HwSeries series_ = HwSeries.B;
        public HwSeries Series
        {
            get { return series_; }
            set
            {
                if (series_ != value)
                {
                    series_ = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Series");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ItemTemplate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:testDemo="clr-namespace:TestDemo"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="DisplayString"/>
                <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="EnumValue"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,5"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
            </Style>

            <!-- Default DataTemplate -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CascadingTemplate" DataType="testDemo:SubVM">
                <Grid Name="PairsGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Name="SeriesTextBlock" Text="Series (With DataTemplate)" 
                               Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ComboBox Name="SeriesComboBox" Grid.Column="1"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding HwSeriesCollection}" SelectedValue="{Binding Series}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="201*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="302*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="SeriesTextBlock" 
                   Text="Series (Without DataTemplate)" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />

        <ComboBox Name="SeriesComboBox" 
                  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding HwSeriesCollection}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Series}"/>

        <ItemsControl 
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Name="CascadingItemsControl" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding CascadingList}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CascadingTemplate}" >
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
namespace ItemTemplate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow 
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainVM();
        }
    }
}
```

Very appreciate for your help!

Comment: what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: all the combobox should display 'B' by default @nit

Comment: working just fine with both 4.0 and 4.5.. can you try clean build the solution.. remove all the temp file and obj folder and then compile and run

Comment: did you try that on a machine that only installed .NET 4 (did NOT install .NET 4.5)?

Comment: no..i tried by changing the targetframework from 4.5 to 4

Comment: the target framework for the project is .NET Framework 4, and it will not work correctly if running the application in the machine that not installed .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by code changes as below

```
<!-- Default DataTemplate -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CascadingTemplate" DataType="testDemo:SubVM">
                <Grid Name="PairsGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Name="SeriesTextBlock" Text="Series (With DataTemplate)" 
                               Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ComboBox Name="SeriesComboBox" Grid.Column="1" 

                    <!-- Specify this explicitly -->
                    SelectedValuePath="EnumValue"

                    ItemsSource="{Binding HwSeriesCollection}" SelectedValue="{Binding Series}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```